# Imprimir el camino mas corto con Algoritmo de Dijkstra (repetidas veces)

Tags: python, imprimir, teoría-de-grafos

Tengo un grafo con sus vértices y aristas (con su peso) lo introduje en código, luego debía encontrar el camino con el algoritmo de dijkstra y también funciono.
Luego se pide que el sistema pueda almacenar varios pedidos por orden de llegada y luego muestre el camino más corto a cada pedido a medida que se entregan (cuando hablo de pedido es referente a que se introduce por teclado el vértice al que se quiere llegar, en este caso son 'n' cantidad de pedidos)

Los vértices son los siguientes
A, B, C, D, F, G, K, H (este último es el punto de partida)

El problema está en que ahora introduje una cola para guardar los "pedidos" a medida que se introducen para posteriormente una vez estén todos dentro, sacarlos uno a uno y mostrar la ruta más corta desde el punto de origen H hasta el que se introduce por teclado, una vez que saco los puntos de la cola se llama el método de dijkstra y este imprime el camino más corto, pero una vez que se vuelve a llamar la función esta ahora no muestra el camino... Y no se a que se debe esto.

Ahora parte del código:

```
def camino(self, a, b):
    camino = []
    actual = b
    while actual != None: # Se actualiza con los vertices con menor costo
        camino.insert(0, actual)
        actual = self.vertices[actual].padre
    return [camino, self.vertices[b].costo]

def minimo(self, l):
    if len(l) > 0:
        m = self.vertices[l[0]].costo
        v = l[0]
        for e in l:
            if m > self.vertices[e].costo:
                m = self.vertices[e].costo
                v = e
        return v
    return None
```

El metodo de dijkstra

```
def dijkstra(self, a):
    if a in self.vertices:
        self.vertices[a].costo = 0
        actual = a
        noVisitados = []
        for v in self.vertices:
            if v != a:
                self.vertices[v].costo = float('inf')
            self.vertices[v].padre = None
            noVisitados.append(v)
        while len(noVisitados) > 0:
            for vec in self.vertices[actual].vecinos:
                if self.vertices[vec[0]].visitado == False:
                    if self.vertices[actual].costo + vec[1] < self.vertices[vec[0]].costo:
                        self.vertices[vec[0]].costo = self.vertices[actual].costo + vec[1] 
                        self.vertices[vec[0]].padre = actual 
            self.vertices[actual].visitado = True
            noVisitados.remove(actual) # Se eliminan del conjunto de no visitados
            actual = self.minimo(noVisitados)
    else:
        return False
```

Primero como se agregan los vertices a la cola, en esta lo hago con bucle while para controlar cuantas veces se hara, esto esta en la clase principal

```
cola = []
resp = input("Realiza un pedido si/no ")
while resp == 'si':
    g = Grafica()
    opcion = input("Punto de entrega: ")
        if opcion == 'A':
            opcion = 2
        elif opcion == 'B':
            opcion = 3
        elif opcion == 'C':
            opcion = 4
        elif opcion == 'D':
            opcion = 5
        elif opcion == 'F':
            opcion = 6
        elif opcion == 'G':
            opcion = 7
        elif opcion == 'K':
            opcion = 8
    cola.append(opcion)
    resp = input("Realizar otro pedido si/no: ")
```

Y luego como se sacan los datos de la cola, lo hago a traves de otro bucle while
el 1 viene siendo la H el punto de partida y el pE es el destino

```
opt = input("mostrar la ruta mas corta si/no: ")
while opt == 'si':
    pE = cola.pop(0)
    print("\n\nLa ruta más rápida por Dijkstra junto con su costo es:")
    g.dijkstra(1)
    print(g.camino(1, pE))
    opt = input("Mostrar la siguiente ruta si/no: ")
```

Se agradece la ayuda :)

Comment: "ahora introduje una cola" ... ¿cual cola? ¿donde está? El código publicado está incompleto, y no puedo ejecutarlo en mi PC. Sin código que trabajar es difícil dar un respuesta segura.

Comment: vale perdon, ya agrege la declaracion de la cola.

Comment: Solo por preguntar no deberia entonces subir la estructura de los vertices y del grafo? ya que si intentas correr este codigo directo de aqui tambien necesitarias eso...

Comment: Lo que se pide es un [ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), o sea, tienes que sacar todo lo que no conduzca al problema (por ejemplo, los `print`). Tu problema parece ser de manejo de colas, que es independiente de Dijkstra.